# deleting all elements of a treeview

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Hi i have got this treeview with checkbox. i want to traverse the whole treeview and delete those items which have not been checked. how to do it? i think we have to write something else in foreach. kindly help

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in this.TreeView1.Nodes)
{
    if (tn.Checked == false)
    {
        int strTreeValue = Convert.ToInt32(tn.Value);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Delete From Role_Menu Where Menu_id=" + strTreeValue, con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the tree view after the for loop.

You need to do the following code after the for loop.

```
  DataTable table= new DatatTable();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Query",Con);
adp.Fill(table,"Table");

TreeView1.DataSource=table;
TreeView.DataBind();
```